# How can I find the correct part for a replacement keyboard for an LG laptop

Tags: laptop, keyboard, replacement, spare-parts

My daughter's laptop (an LG 13U70P) has an A key that broke off.  (The base part that connects it is broken.) I've replaced laptop keyboards before, but it's been a while.

Just finding the correct keyboard replacement part to order has been a pain.  Either I'm looking in the wrong place, or the information is hard to find, or both.

So two questions:

Which keyboard will be a compatible replacement part?

Is there a relatively easy way to find this information?
[image: The Keyboard in Question]

Comment: Just go on Amazon, search for "LG 13U70P keyboard" and select section "Laptop Computer Replacement Parts".

Comment: @harrymc That would be great if that worked.  Doing that doesn't seem to give any useful results.  I'll try again when I get home, maybe the phone app gives different results.